# Open and close tag blocks in VIM

Tags: html, vim

In Vim I want to wrap a block inside tags like in the image made in sublime.

[image: example in the sublime]

Comment: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/fold.html

Answer (score 3):

What you are referring to is called folds, there are multiple ways to create folds in vim, see `:h 'foldmethod` for a starting point, or really you should read `:h usr_28.txt` for a proper explanation.